# Table sort works wrong when the hour is changed - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular6

I have a weird problem with ordering dates on a table. I want to sort the table according to resDate column (in increasing order). In 
[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kq2eny) stackblitz if I click `resDate` title the dates are sorted wrong but if I change the 4th row of the logs' `insdate` to `'05.09.2018 08:23:41'` instead of `'05.09.2018 10:23:41'` (in which I only changed hour from `10` to `08`) then it is sorting correctly. Or instead of the logs array there if I use

```
 logs = [
        { insdate: '11.12.2018 06:41:25', resdate: '13.09.2018 06:41:26' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:24 ', resdate: '21.10.2018 06:42:24' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:29', resdate: '10.12.2018 06:42:29'},
        { insdate: '12.12.2018 06:45:00', resdate: '12.12.2018 06:45:00' },
        { insdate: '11.12.2018 06:45:47', resdate: '11.12.2018 06:45:47' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42', resdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42' },
        { insdate: '10.12.2018 06:46:42', resdate: '' },
        { insdate: '', resdate: '12.12.2018 07:16:50' },
    ];
```

this one again it is working correctly. What is wrong with the stackblitz I provided? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While sorting in increasing order, do want the nulll/empty  dates to appear at the top or at the bottom?

Comment: I dont have a preference but I thought that since they are null they would be lesser than any other date that is why they would be on top.

Comment: Okay, try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-burq5n?file=src/app/app.component.ts see if it fits your requirement?

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. It is what I have wanted. Thank you very much.